# JavaScript events and strange behaviour after deletion process

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I have a table, on each row (the `tr` tag) three events are set `onclick`, `onmouseout` and `onmouseover`.
For each row, the first three `td` tag contains an `onclick` event.

```
<tr onclick="javascript:getWSData(...)" onmouseout="this.className=clTwo" onmouseover="this.className=clThree">
    <td onclick="popDivInfo(false, verRicDivCreaInfo('details'))">
        Details
    </td> 
    <td onclick="popDivInfo(false, verRicDivCreaInfo('edit'))">
        Edit
    </td> 
    <td onclick="if(confirm('Are you sure?')) {getWSData('delete');event.stopPropagation(); } else {alert('Cancelled!')}">
        Delete
    </td> 
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
</tr>
```

As far as I know: as soon a `td`'s `onclick` is triggered the default event chain should execute it for first and then should execute `tr`'s `onclick`. And this is OK for me.
But, in case of deletion (the third `td`), I don't want that event chain goes forward, so I used  `event.stopPropagation()`;

The standard behaviour is quite correct, but I got one single problem: as soon deletion happens either *Details* either *Edit* `td` stop working. The first click (after the deletion) doesn't working at its best (I'm not completely aware of what happening) while deletion still working. When I click a second time both td's `onclick` (Details & Edit) are newly completely working.

Few more things:

- The behaviour is perfectly correct before a deletion
- Every deletion action delete its `tr` using jQuery `remove` method (nothing happens if I comment this instruction)
- When this issue happens, this happens on the entire columns (Details and Edit)
- The issue doesn't happen if I don't confirm the deletion process
- The `tr`'s `onclick` is always fully working
- The first click (after a deletion) on *Details* or *Edit* indeed partially start a JavaScript action (because a pre-loading is launched) but this action is not completed.
- Even if the td action is not completed, the `tr` action is always executed, so there aren't un-useful `stopPropagation()`

Any ideas? I have no ideas at all.

Comment: Are you sure you're not setting event.stopPropagation() for all events?

Comment: I haven't do it explicitely, my fear is that it is implicitly setted by something else.

Comment: Your example works fine for me, see [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dmalinovsky/H3dP7/).  You must be doing something else in the other code.

Comment: @FranciscoAfonso the tr action is always executed even when td action goes in trouble. So there aren't unusefull stopPropagation().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I remember `tr` is something like virtual markup unit. This is only for group elements like `tbody` for example. It doesn't take a part in event bubbling at all. So you shouldn't bind any events on it. We can see this in example: http://jsfiddle.net/z9vVM/. Here you see that event binded to `tr` element has target `td` anyway, not `tr` as desired.
Binding event to `tr` is the same as you give all `td` in that row some class and bind event to that classes – `tr` is only the way to group elements.
This is why your `stopPropagation` doesn't work. There is no any propagation at all.

The way you can work this all around – is manipulating with classes. Take a look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/RZscw/1/